# Execute echo command in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an encoded object containing array of layers which is sent through an ajax call to some php file say myfile.php. The php file simply decodes this object and pushes the layers name into the database. Now i want to show layerName in front end which is currently pushing to the database.

My ajax request is as follows:

```
$.ajax(
 {
  type: 'POST',
  url: "funcs.php",
  data: 
  {
   targetAction : 'getProjectAssetId',
   MetaData: allFiles,
  },
  success: function(data)
  {
    console.log("data: "+data);
  },
//dataType: "json"
});
```

Funcs.php encoded object handling is as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['MetaData']))
{

    $project= explode("ProjectTag",$_POST['MetaData']);  
    echo "\nProject: ".$project[0]."\n";

    $projectName=explode("Bounds: ",$project[0]);
    $projectBounds=$projectName[1];
    $projectName=explode("ProjectName:",$projectName[0]);
    $projectName=$projectName[1];
    echo "ProjectName: ".($projectName)."\n"."ProjectBounds: ".$projectBounds."\n";
    $bound=json_decode($projectBounds,true);
    // Hard coded groupID and no reference ID
    $projectId= getProjectAssetId($projectName,25,'',$bound,''); // inserting Project Name in DB with hardcoded groupID and no reference
    echo "\n ProjectId: ".$projectId."\n";
    $files=explode(",oneFileTag,",$project[1]);


    for($fileCounter=0;$fileCounter<count($files);$fileCounter++)
     {
         $message='Adding Layer: '.$files[$fileCounter];
        echo'<scripttype="text/javascript">alert(\'asd\');notification("'.$message.'",2,"loading"); </script>';

        $Layer=explode("LayerFieldTag",$desFileFields[0]);
        $LayerName=explode("LayerName:",$Layer[0]);
        $LayerName=$LayerName[1]; 
        echo "\n\n\nLayerName: ".($LayerName)."\n";

        $typeId= getLayerAssetType($LayerName,1);       
        $layerId=getLayerAssetId($LayerName,$projectId);

        echo "\ntypeid: ".$typeId."\n";
        echo "\nLayerid: ".$layerId."\n";

    }
```

I want to execute javascript function in for loop, I mean I want to show all filenames in a dialog which is written in js files. The issue i am facing is it would be called by an echo but this echo would be caught on success function of ajax request. I want to execute this echo command.

Comment: Create an array that is populated in the loop, and then echo it as json_encoded string after the loop

Comment: Hello sir i want javascript function to be called at each iteration. I want to show user progress of all files.

Comment: @user2174920 There is nothing in your question which asks for `showing progress` to a user, be clear of what you really want to solve here

Comment: You need to write to a file and tail it using another php called by ajax

Comment: sorry sir if u missunderstood it or i misguided it. Actualll i want to bind an event with ajax which shows user that this file is being loaded but the issue is this all filehandling is done in php file

Comment: @mplungjan again there would issue with ajax

Comment: So you want to display real-time progress, like a real-time % of how much has been completed or just that the file is being loaded in general?

Answer (score 1):

You have your JS callback logic in the wrong place.  As a rule, avoid writing Javascript logic in with PHP.

Instead, you should return a JSON array from your PHP file, then move the for loop to the JS success callback, and loop through the JSON array response there.

For example, something like...

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function(files) {
    for (var i in files) {
        alert('asd');
        notification('Adding Layer: ' + files[i], 2, 'loading');
    }
}
```

Based on looking at your JS and PHP I would HIGHLY recommend spending more time learning best practices and coding style guidelines before proceeding too much further.  Take the time and care to learn how to become a skilled developer.